# Remove Add to Cart button in Woocommerce but keep variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good day,

I need to hide the add to art button in WooCommerce, without affecting pricing or dropdowns and variations. I am using WPForms for the adding to cart and checking out and ONLY do not want to display the Add to Cart button anywhere on the site.

Thus far I have used this snippet to remove the Add to Cart from shop and product page:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

This works until I add a variable product, where it hides the Add to Cart button, but also hides the variation dropdown, so I used this snippet:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
```

This hides the Add to Cart button and displays the variation dropdown.

The problem is, both snippets do no work together, they basically override each other.

Is there a snippet that can help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Does it matter how you hide it? If not, you can use CSS

```
a.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart{ 
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that did not work. Thank you though

Comment: What do you mean? You may have to change the class name to the one on your theme but CSS should hide the buttons sitewide.

Comment: Silly me, Works like a bomb! Thank you.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but where can I see the class name used on my theme @RayEssop?